# How to check if network is available from a AWX running container to a LDAP server?

Tags: docker, ldap, ping, containers, ansible-tower

I want to connect to a LDAP server from an AWX installed server.
Used docker-compose installed AWX. So it's running inside container.
I can ping LDAP server IP from the server running AWX container. But can't ping LDAP server inside the AWX container.

```
docker exec -it [container_id] /bin/sh
ping [IP]
```

How to use ping inside container? If I can't confirm whether the AWX container can connect to LDAP server, I can't config the right LDAP integration successfully.
It always return this error:

```
awx.sso.backends Encountered an error authenticating to LDAP
```

Comment: You can try netcat: `nc my.ldap.server ldapPort`

Comment: @JurajMartinka Do you mean inside container?

Comment: Yes, inside the container.